# I keep getting 404 error while trying to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have two separate login forms, one for users and one for admins.

The problem is that Spring ignores the config paramter for `loginProcessingUrl`, for the admin as well as for the user. Whenever I try to login, it gives me 404 error.

While I was using `RequestMatchers()`, it worked perfectly but just for one of them (user or admin) but not both. So I switched to `SecurityMatcher()` which does restrict the users from accessing any path such as `/admin/**` or `/user/**` without login but the problem is that the login is not working.
Can someone help me with this?

Config class:

```java
package com.business.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.business.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailService;

    @Bean
    public static BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailService);

        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
        throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Order(1)
    public static class UserSecurityConfig {

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .securityMatcher("/user/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ROLE_USER")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/user-login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/userLogin")
                    .permitAll()
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/home")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403");
            return http.build();
        }
    }

    @Order(2)
    public static class AdminSecurityConfig {

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .securityMatcher("/admin/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/admin-login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/adminLogin")
                    .permitAll()
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403");
            return http.build();
        }
    }

    @Order(3)
    public static class GeneralSecurityConfig {

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain3(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers()
                    .frameOptions().disable();

            return http.build();
        }
    }
}
```

Admin login page:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
th:replace="~{base::layout(~{::section})}">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Universal Education : Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div class="background-img">
        <div class="container auth-container-login bg-white">
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="text-center mb-3">Admin Login</h3>
                <div th:if="${register}" class="text-center mb-2">
                    <h6 th:text="${register}" class="text-success"></h6>
                    <th:block></th:block>
                </div>

                <!-- Pills navs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified mb-3" id="ex1"
                    role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a
                        class="nav-link active" id="tab-login" data-mdb-toggle="pill"
                        href="#pills-login" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-login"
                        aria-selected="true">Login</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link"
                        id="tab-register" data-mdb-toggle="pill" href="/admin-register"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-register" aria-selected="false">Register</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Pills navs -->
                <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Email
                    and Password</div>
                <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                    Successfully Logged Out</div>
                <!-- Pills content -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-login"
                        role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-login">
                        <form th:action="@{/adminLogin}" method="post">
                            <!-- Email input -->
                            <div class="form-outline mb-2">
                                <input type="email" id="loginName" class="form-control"
                                    name="email" /> <label class="form-label" for="loginName">Email</label>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Password input -->
                            <div class="form-outline mb-2">
                                <input type="password" id="loginPassword" class="form-control"
                                    name="password" /> <label class="form-label"
                                    for="loginPassword">Password</label>
                            </div>

                            <!-- 2 column grid layout -->
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <!-- Submit button -->
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-2">Sign
                                        in</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row mb-2">
                                    <!-- Simple link -->
                                    <a href="#!">Forgot password?</a>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Register buttons -->
                                <p>
                                    Not a member? <a th:href="@{/user-register}">Register</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- Pills content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot :

[This is what I get when I try to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u24Ql.png)

Comment: Your methods should not be static at first

Comment: @HarryCoder I referred to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-two-login-pages

Comment: Show your request with URL, body and header. For example a screemshot of your dev tool in your browser (F12).

Comment: You are using the wrong URL. Instead of `/userLogin` you have to use `/user/userLogin`.

Comment: @dur tried changing it, still not working, same issue. I don't think the issue is with the URL, the login works fine while using `requestMatchers()` but out of 2 filter chains only one would work so I had to switch to `securityMatcher()` .

Comment: The URL is wrong. If you get the same error (at least the URL should changed in the error) you have a second problem. Did you change `.loginProcessingUrl("/userLogin")` to `.loginProcessingUrl("/user/userLogin")`? And also changed your HTML?

Comment: @dur yes, I did that., still not working :( . Also if the URL was a problem, how does it work properly while using `requestMatchers()` ?

Comment: If you add `requestMatchers()` only one chain is exceuted and this chain defines processing URL, which is accessabe in the chain. If you restrict that chain, the processing URL is not accessible anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had followed the same tutorial link you posted in the comments. I encountered similar issues and came to a resolution by combining that tutorial with this second one [Multiple Login Pages](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/multiple-login-pages-examples)

Essentially, I kept both static classes in the SecurityConfig file as described by the baeldung tutorial but instead of configuring a SecurityFilterChain I used the configure method to establish both logins.

Comment: To use configure method, we'll need to extend webconfigureradapter, which is now deprecated right?

Comment: @ThomasShelby I extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter however I did not notice the difference in Spring version. The version of Spring used in our project is 5.3.9, if you are using a newer version which it appears to be so, you could also try using WebSecurityCustomizer.

Here's a link referring to the changes: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

I would have to attempt a sample using the newer Spring versions. Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: i am using version 6.0.2